# NFS on Btrfs on multi-devices .vs. Glusterfs on distributed-volume?

Tags: nfs, dovecot, glusterfs, btrfs

I considering a storage for Email. 
This storage system run on my own private cloud (already replicated), then i does not care about replication.

I'm thinking about 2 options:

1- I will create few "disk" (volume on cloud), and create a Btrfs filesytem on multi-disk; and when filesystem full, i'll create more "disk" and add it to btrfs file system by:

```
btrfs device add /dev/vdX /mnt

btrfs filesystem balance /mnt
```

This mount point (/mnt) will be expose over NFS, and my Dovecot server will mount this export, and store emails on it.

2- I will create few "disk" (volume on cloud), and create a GlusterFS distributed-volume accross these disks; and when filesystem full, i'll create more "disk" and add new "disk"(s) to GlusterFS distributed-volume, an re-balance it.
My Dovecote will mount this volume using glusterfs-client, and store emails on it.

(Repeat: i don't need replicate, because my "disk", volume on private cloud, replicated underhood)

Do you think which option have better:

- performance? (many many small read/write I/O)
- stable?
- flexible?

Answer (score 4):

You have to consider the I/O pattern of a mail server: Read/write *many* small files as fast as possible. Both your variants are really unsuitable for this when dealing with a large number of clients, IMHO.

Neither FS is fast enough, and I guess especially the locking overhead of GlusterFS will be significant. Then you add another layer with NFS, which has it's own overhead. Instead of this, I would try to connect the mail store with as small overhead as possible and with a fast file system. Usually this means to connect as directly to the physical storage as possible, but since you hide your architecture behind bullshit bingo terms like "private cloud", we don't know what would be possible.

One approach you could try would be to export the storage via iSCSI to the mail server and then use a FS that's fast with many small files and maybe, if it's really important, use LVM to be able to easily add space to that FS in the form of additional iSCSI volumes (which adds back some overhead).

Whatever you try though: You have to benchmark the different variants and see if you get the required performance out of it.

Comment: "private cloud" means i'm running on OpenStack, and my "disk" is volume of Openstack.

Comment: I need to export storage over something like NFS or Glusterfs because this will be mounted on multi dovecot server.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to choose one from the two above then NFS is preferable I think.

GlusterFS looses all its benefits as distributed filesystem in your setup since OpenStack
volumes are still mounted from a central storage. It is neither more stable nor 
more smart since It should care about distributed file locking while NFS locking
is done on a sigle server.

I am no sure that combining your storage from multiple devices is a good idea. Alternatively
you may consider skipping high level OpenStack volume service fucntionality and exposing your storage directly - formated LVM(/ZFS/SAN) volume exported by NFS. Going this way you will eliminate unnecessary iSCSI level and will be able to encrease the mail storage space on demand as long as the main storage has enough free space.

Comment: I want to hide complicated below, and only use volume (of OpenStack) as disk. When my mail storage nearly full, i simply create new volume and attach it to server. Therefore, i need a FS that can combine multi-drives Safe(not lose data on any situation)  & Efficient(fast "enough"). I think about few options like: Ext4 on LVM, Btrfs on multi-devices, Glusterfs with distributed-volume, mhddfs, unionfs, aufs,... Which do you think it's best for my use-case? Thank you!

Comment: I understood your point but for performance reasons It is better to keep the storage stack as simple as possible. Ideally as SvW suggests. But you need shared storage You said. Then my answer is a next approach.

Comment: ... and even more, multi-drive local filesystem like brtfs usually implies stripping, in your case - stripping over iSCSI volumes wich is generaly bad idea. GlusterFS is desined to work in such enviroment but I am afraid you will be disappointed of its performance for your load pattern. As well as I can not see any oprational benefits of OpenStack tools in this case.